# how to convert code to winform?

Tags: c#

Writing my first C# application...never touched the language before and not much of a programmer! I have been googling around and got a few books but thought the best way to learn is to actually try some coding!

Anyway, been asked to write a little inventory system for all our 15000 servers and I can do this in powershell fine but wanted a challenge and try my hand at C#.

I have the below code and this works fine in a command propmpt window but how to I put this into a winform app? I assume I need to change the "Console.WriteLine" to something else...just I do not know what the something else is! I will probably add in a listbox to show the details in there rather than executing a command prompt..

I will be ading in loads of stuff - like memory info and disk sizes etc so getting this right would help me...plus, no doubt I will ask loads of questions!

Code that works:

```
using System;

namespace OsVersionSample

{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Operating System Detaiils");
            OperatingSystem os = Environment.OSVersion;
            Console.WriteLine("OS Version: " + os.Version.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("OS Platoform: " + os.Platform.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("OS SP: " + os.ServicePack.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("OS Version String: " + os.VersionString.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine();

            // Get Version details

            Version ver = os.Version;
            Console.WriteLine("Major version: " + ver.Major);
            Console.WriteLine("Major Revision: " + ver.MajorRevision);
            Console.WriteLine("Minor version: " + ver.Minor);
            Console.WriteLine("Minor Revision: " + ver.MinorRevision);
            Console.WriteLine("Build: " + ver.Build);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Code I want to put into a winform:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Operating System Detaiils");

            OperatingSystem os = Environment.OSVersion;

            Console.WriteLine("OS Version: " + os.Version.ToString());

            Console.WriteLine("OS Platoform: " + os.Platform.ToString());

            Console.WriteLine("OS SP: " + os.ServicePack.ToString());

            Console.WriteLine("OS Version String: " + os.VersionString.ToString());

            Console.WriteLine();



            // Get Version details

            Version ver = os.Version;

            Console.WriteLine("Major version: " + ver.Major);

            Console.WriteLine("Major Revision: " + ver.MajorRevision);

            Console.WriteLine("Minor version: " + ver.Minor);

            Console.WriteLine("Minor Revision: " + ver.MinorRevision);

            Console.WriteLine("Build: " + ver.Build);



            Console.ReadLine(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you talk about a listbox, why haven't you tried using one? It's not hard to add a listbox, and then add lines to it.

Comment: You're not supposed to downvote everything except the accepted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tou can add listbox to form and do something like this

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
    listbox1.items.add("Operating System Detaiils");
     OperatingSystem os = Environment.OSVersion;
listbox1.items.add("OS Version: " + os.Version.ToString());
    // and so on...

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Forms typically use textboxes, labels, drop downs and other graphical controls to display information. The core libraries to access information remains same.

For example, Label.Text property can be used to display information.

Answer (score -1):

Console.Writeline in winform...really?

Add some other control (say a list box or textbox) then you can use these controls' properties (like textbox1.text) for displaying the output.

Just for test purpose - change all console.writeline to MessageBox.Show